# Insert quantity of each types of item

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm confused on how to actually let my form insert the data into the bag table that I have created. The system is supposed to store the bag of the customer where the `bag_id` is the `customer id`.

[image: This is how the data is supposed to be inserted for the number of bag of each type]

The number of rows generated for each customer in the bag table is dependent on the sizes of the bag they are storing.

[image: How the table are related to each other]

**The picture below is how I want the data to be inserted.**

[image: How the data in table look like]

However, I can't figure out how to insert the data the way I wanted. This is what I try to do to get the number of each type of size:

```
<label>Bag Size</label></br>
     <input type="text" name="big" id="big" class="form-control" style="width:5%;"/><label>Big</label>
     <input type="text" name="medium" id="medium" class="form-control"style="width:5%;" /><label>Medium</label>
     <input type="text" name="small" id="small" class="form-control"style="width:5%;" /><label>Small</label>
```

Any suggestion on the way to enter the data is appreciated.

Comment: the `big`, `medium` and `small` are text inputs?  do they take the quantity of each type of bags that would be saved against the user?

Comment: if the customer makes an order , will you have to insert to these two tables ?

Comment: Hi, this is more to an inventory system. The customer will store their bag and the storekeeper will record the bag id. The only table that will be updated is the bag table if the customer data is inserted. The price table is only a table that set the price of each bag for each sizes. Yes, they take the quantity of each bag the user have and input it according to the size. The way I illustrate the content of the table in database may not be completely right. Therefore, are there any suggestion?